# Implicit differentiation with Scilab?

Tags: scilab, calculus, derivative

Can somebody tell me how to implicitly differentiate equations in **Scilab**?

**Example:**

```
x^2+y^2=25
(a circle equation)
```

**The derivative is:**

```
dy/dx=−x/y
```

How can we accomplish this implicit differentiation in Scilab?
May be with diff or dassl or another function of Scilab?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... Please read for your future questions http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: Scilab is primarily for _numerical_ computations. If you need symbolic differentiation, look elsewhere, e.g., at [SageMath](http://www.sagemath.org/)

Comment: @NormalHuman is right. Are you looking for something like [automatic differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation)? I did a quick search and found [ad](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ad), [algopy](https://pythonhosted.org/algopy/), [pyAutoDiff](http://www.datacommunitydc.org/blog/2013/05/pyautodiff-automatic-differentiation-for-numpy), and according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29265465/3904031) you can use [SymPy](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/calculus.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scilab is oriented to numerical computations. You can go to http://www.wolframalpha.com and type "differentiate x^2 + y^2 = 25 in x" into the input box.